# How to parse list of expression using menhir?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir

Here are my current [lexer](https://github.com/vsiles/tiger/blob/6032e643fd307ee9c7fdd8b91b6bbd17ac6a3ecd/src/lexer.mll) and [parser](https://github.com/vsiles/tiger/blob/6032e643fd307ee9c7fdd8b91b6bbd17ac6a3ecd/src/parser.mly) for Andrew Appel's Tiger language (ocaml).

I'm currently trying to support mutual recursive functions, but the following parser code doesn't work:

```
decs :
    | l = list(dec) { l }

dec :
    | t = nonempty_list(loc(tydec)) { S.TypeDec t }
    | v = loc(vardec) { S.VarDec v }
    | f = nonempty_list(loc(fundec)) { S.FunDec f }

%inline fundec :
    | Function fun_name = symbol LPar params = tyfields RPar
        Eq body = loc(exp) {
        S.{ fun_name; args = params; return_type = None; body }
    }
    | Function fun_name = symbol LPar params = tyfields RPar
        Colon result_type = symbol Eq body = loc(exp) {
        S.{ fun_name; args = params; return_type = Some result_type; body }
    }
```

For the small example:

```
let
    function f1(x : int) : int =
        f2(x)

    function f2(x : int) : int =
        f1(x)

in
    f1 (0)
end
```

I get two `FunDec` tokens with a singleton list instead of a single `FunDec` token with a list made of two elements.

How can I use menhir to parse a list of `fundec` ?

PS: I know I can merge these list in a second pass, but I'd like the parser to do it for me if possible

Comment: Could you put all of the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @PatJ I added the fundec parsing rule, but I'm not sure what more you want. I linked the two relevant files + the exemple code. Putting the whole parser file will clobber the question, won't it ?

Comment: It's just that site policy says any post should be self-containing, in case a link gets dead. Even though github is probably not going to disappear anytime soon, your repository might.

Comment: My bad, you are right. I think the current content is enough for the question, but I'll add more details if anyone requires some specific part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no marker for a group of functions, you have to declare your list yourself, with several constructors:

```
decs :
    | hd=nonempty_list(fundec) tl=decs_no_function { (S.Fundecs hd)::tl }
    | l=decs_no_function { l }

decs_no_functions :
    | hd=dec tl=decs { hd::tl } (* dec same as yours, without functions *)
    | { [] }
```

Here `decs_no_functions` corresponds to "any list of declaration that does not start with a function". Note that a single function declaration will be inside a single element list.

Comment: It is working nicely for functions. Now I'm trying to do the same to have function _and_ types management in the same way. I'll validate when I'll succeed ;) Thank you for the tip